# Schwarz' theorem application

Tags: real-analysis

I'm wondering about this problem :

We have $ f$ which has continuous second partial derivatives at any given point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with

$f_x=3x+ay^2$, $f_y=bxy+2y$ and $f_y(1,1)=3$.

Find $a$ and $b$ and a function $f$ which satisfies these.

I have found b=1 and thought about using Schwarz' theorem but do not know how to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: If you use Schwarz' theorem, what is the equation that results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Schwarz's Theorem  we have  $$f_{xy}=f_{yx} $$ since your function has  continuous second order derivatives. Thus we  derive $f_x$ wrt  $y$, and derive  $f_y$ wrt  $x$, so you get  $$ 2ay=by$$  and this holds for all $y$. As   $b=1$ then  $a=\frac{1}{2}$.